# Sending data with html form created in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm creating a form in a response like:

```
router.post('/resetPassword/confirm', async (req, res) => {
  var username = {
    iv: req.query.c1,
    content: req.query.c2
  };
  var realUsername = decrypt(username);

  res.send(`
    <!-- some styling etc -->
    <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="http://myIP:60702/user/resetChange?user=${realUsername}">
      <label for="pwd1">Passwort:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd1" placeholder="Passwort" name="pwd1" minlength="8" pattern="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[[A-Za-z]).{8,}" required>
      <label for="pwd2">Passwort wiederholen:</label>
      <input type="password" id="pwd" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" name="pwd2" minlength="8" pattern="(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[[A-Za-z]).{8,}" required>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    `);
});
```

And it definitely sends data to an HTTP address. The router of this address is defined like:

```
router.post('/resetChange', async (req, res) => { ...
```

But when clicking on the submit button of the form it still tries to send the data to
`https://myIP:60702/user/resetChange?user=t5@test.de`

Why is it trying to send the data over https and not just http?
I'm running the same code on my home system and it works fine. On the v-server (node running with pm2) it's giving this error.

Comment: because in the action you have added is `http://myIP:60702/user/resetChange?user=${realUsername}`. so when you submit the form it goes to that particular url

Comment: @HelloWorld I want it to got to http://... but instead it goes to https://....

Comment: do you have redirection to https for that domain or route?

Comment: @HelloWorld As far as I know I dont. It never redirected to https before. Just with that form..